# Text going to a new page without 'complete' the previous page

Tags: margins

First post here in TeX forum, I hope there's not too much trouble.

Since one image worth more than words, you can see a print of the problem I'm  having in this image[image]
It seems that this problems happens whenever I have an equation array at the top of the next page. (I could post other prints like this (actually worse), where I have an equation array right after the page with the bottom margin issue).

And my documment settings it's here: (sorry for the mess)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\numberwithin{equation}{section} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{varwidth}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage[top=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\parindent=1.5cm

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
```

Comment: Welcome. What we need is a complete minimal document i.e. a small amount of code we can copy-paste and compile to reproduce the problem. On this site, an image is rarely worth a thousand words because we are much more interested in the code responsible for the image. If you give us the code, we should be able to make the image ourselves!

Comment: Also, don't use the option `pdftex` for those packages. And `hyperref` needs to be loaded *late*. Very few packages should be loaded later. (There are exceptions, but they are precisely that: exceptions.) And don't load packages twice - especially not with different options as you do. Also... er... what are we looking at in that picture exactly?

Comment: hello, sorry for the bad post but I solved the issue. The problem was happening because of the set of equations written on an equation array that was too big to be printed in the bottom of the  above page shown in the figure, so latex printed in the next page, hence the gap beetween the text of the above page and it's bottom margin. (I dont know if my explanation it's understandable - I'm not a native speaker)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op realized that a large math display would be taken completely to a new page rather than breaking in the middle at the bottom of a page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was due to code not provided in the question and has been solved by the OP. (See comments.) Since the problem is not present in the question, even users with the same problematic output due to the same problematic code are unlikely to find the question of any assistance, and answers cannot solve a problem their authors have no knowledge of.

Comment: That's why questions should always include minimal documents which can be used to reproduce the problem (output or compilation error, depending on the question). Our crystal balls just aren't what they used to be ;).